# Is there a way to access the Date Modified time of a file in C?

Tags: c, windows, timestamp

Working in Windows, if you access the properties for a file you'll see a line like the following after Date Modified:

```
‎Wednesday, ‎September ‎14, ‎2016, ‏‎15:08:45
```

Is there a way to access this information about a file using C? I'm working in Windows and am restricted to Visual Studio .Net 2003.

Comment: yes have you tried `stat` [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)

Comment: I'll read into this; thank you.

Answer (score 2):

if you want it Windows-specific:

- open the file with CreateFile(Name, READ_ATTRIBUTES,...)
- then GetFileTimes()
- then CloseHandle()
- then take those times you are interested in, and convert them to your locale. Details here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/188768/info-working-with-the-filetime-structure

Answer (score 0):

If you want it non-Windows-specific:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

struct stat stbuf;
stat(filename, &stbuf);
struct tm *tmp = localtime(&stbuf.st_mtime);
char tmpbuf[30];
strftime(tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf), "%c", tmp);
printf("%s: %s\n", filename, tmpbuf);
```